# ActiveRecord to execute a single SQL statement to destroy based included dependent model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

Consider a scenario where I have an ActiveRecord model `Document` that has a `has_many` relation with subdependent model `File`. I can eager load the files for a given parent `Document` using a query such as:

```
document_with_files = Document.includes(:files).find_by(document_id: document_id)
```

Is there a way in ActiveRecord to delete the parent document if there is only one child file as part of the same SQL statement? I've tried something like the following and it's quite close:

```
Document.select("document.*, COUNT(files.id) file_count")
        .joins(:files)
        .group("document.id")
        .where(document_id: document_id_to_be_found)
        .where("file_count = ?", 1)
```

It seems that my assignment of `file_count` isn't being recognized in the final `.where` clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your scenario, the following code could find the document which only has one child file.

`Document.joins(:files).group('documents.id').having('count(files.id) = 1')`

And if you want to delete the parent document if there is only one child file as part of the same SQL statement.

```
Document.joins(:files)
        .group('documents.id')
        .having('count(files.id) = 1')
        .find_by(document_id: document_id_to_be_found)
        .destroy
```